# wubi18042r333 is not opening on Windows 7 x64 UEFI

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, wubi

- Wubi is `wubi18042r333.exe`
- Ubuntu ISO is `Ubuntu-18.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`

I have tried to open Wubi with internet connected, and disconnected, but with no success 
 (`python27.dll`, `wubi~.exe`, and `ubuntu~.iso` are all in the same directory)

Python 2.7 (x64 & x86) are installed and added to `PATH`:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Python27;C:\Python27-32bit
```

I have inspected the `%temp%` folder and 2 files are created (uploaded to [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/whv41li9h9doqsf/AADqxSFv4jAYXdZE7bmWK8O9a?dl=0)).

Comment: WUBI is completely dead, why are you using it? Also not compatible with UEFI. And soon, in a matter of days, Windows 7 will be dead as well. You seriously need to rethink your strategies about operating systems. Why not just install Ubuntu 18.04 the proper way? You can even do a dual-boot but, again, Windows 7 will be outof support in a few days.

Comment: go to this link - https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi

Comment: Interesting, an unofficial fork I wasn't aware of. Maybe an interesting exercise but doesn't mean it is any less DEAD. Why exactly are you NOT installing Ubuntu properly? Not even when Wubi was supported and included in the Ubuntu ISO that was a proper way to install it, it was intended as some sort of trial run.

Comment: I tried to install Ubuntu in separate partition some years ago but faced some problems with the disk table - the window was NOT booting that time-- ... so that's why I don't want to install in separate and want to try it only for the time being.

Comment: Live sessions is what we use to try distros. If you need help with dual-booting we can do that too. When you know what you're doing things work, when you don't they don't. BIOS and UEFI have different methods and requirements that you must know.

Comment: I know about Live sessions. But I don't want to use it. --- I have even tried to install ubuntu 13.04 which has official Wubi- but that Wubi failed to install ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: FYI: https://askubuntu.com/q/221835/880592 This is what you need to know about dual-booting in UEFI systems. Very easy to learn. Now, what you want to do so obstinately is at least 10x harder and for guaranteed poor results, Ubuntu installed the way Wubi did never worked better that a virtual machine and that you can do easily, Virtualbox is free.

Comment: VirtualBox does not give access to physical components of pc, for example VirtualBox/ VMware uses NAT instead of wifi device/driver.I don't want to dual boot. I will rather consider purchasing an old pc if Wubi does not work.

Comment: One of things I mentioned in the beginning was that you should install Ubuntu, period. There's no pint in keeping Windows 7 around if you value your privacy and security. The only valid reason to keep is to upgrade to Windows 10. But if want to insist in Wubi then good luck and good bye. No one will help you that here.

Comment: Wubi is not a problem... actually bcdedit.exe is real problem... 

If I use the command in cmd as admin `C:\Windows\system32>C:\Windows\sysnative\bcdedit`
then i get the following message
`The boot configuration data store could not be opened.
The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no
longer valid.`

I have manually recreated the EFI partition and bcd store last week while windows was not booting.

Comment: @Amin `BCDedit` is not the issue, as it's a program to edit the BCD store. You've mentioned unsupported software & OSes - please consider looking for up-to-date software & OS solutions. _(I'm perplexed why you mentioned installing Ubuntu 13.04... it's 6 years old & no longer supported by Canonical. Windows 7 loses all support & security updates in 3 weeks, and due to the fact Windows patches show exactly where & how to exploit no-longer supported Windows versions, Windows 7 shouldn't be used after [Jan 14, 2020](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet))_

Comment: I want to quit windows 7 before Jan 14, 2020, on one of my laptops... and maybe upgrade to ubuntu. I want to test Ubuntu 18.04/19.04. when unofficial Wubi was not working then I tried to use the official Wubi in ubuntu 13.04 just for the purpose of testing the unofficial Wubi's bugs if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not Wubi problem. it was bcdedit store problem.

I deleted the EFI partition and re-created the boot record and EFI partition-- now Ubuntu Wubi is installed and working fine.